# Get all the paragraph of a class

Tags: javascript, html, class, paragraph, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to echo all the paragraphs of a specific class. The source code has this structure:

```
<div class='example'> 
  <p> this is the first paragraph </p> 
  <p> this is the second paragraph </p>
</div>
```

I have tried different ways (`getElementsByTagName` and stuff like this but they didn't work). Could you suggest me something?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Since you have attached the `php` tag, you most likely mean the [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). I see some answers in JavaScript. Please clarify this point. You should also show your code ([mcve])

Answer (score 1):

**Simply get the value by classname.**

Use Js Function [getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Try below code for Javascript :

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example").innerHtml;
console.log(x);
alert(x);
```

Also working jsfiddle with javascript - https://jsfiddle.net/ayh0gk7s/1/

If you are prefer to use jQuery then try below code :

```
$('.example p')
```

jsfiddle link for jquery - https://jsfiddle.net/3nhb1agu/

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery`:

```
$('.example p')
```

This should hopefully get you the desired paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch them via XPath:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('file.html');
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$pars = $xp->query('//div[contains(@class, "example")]/p');
// For exactly one class:
//$pars = $xp->query('//div[@class = "example"]/p');

foreach ($pars as $p) {
  var_dump($p->nodeValue);
}
```

The code fetches text representations of the paragraph nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery, you can print the parent children element. Try this !

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.example").children("p").each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
    console.log($(this).text());
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll`.

```
var myParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.example p');

for (var i = 0 ; i < myParagraphs.length ; i++) {
  console.log(myParagraphs[i]);
}
```